# Find rows in SQL that with date when it is stored as datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

My problem is this (using SQL Server 2008 R2).

There is some date columns with types as `datetime`.

So the original intention with the column was to store a date without any time.

Then `datetime` was chosen as datatype.

Sure it works but as the database is also logically connected to a UML-diagram I want to use the right datatype.

An example the column `Parcel.DateofArrival` has the type `datetime`.

There maybe rows that are

```
2011-08-05 00:00:00.000
```

this is a date. But if there is rows like

```
2011-08-05 07:30:00.000
```

it is a `datetime`.

Now I want to find a query that list rows only containing dates, not `datetime`.

Any hint ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to do this is:

```
select p.*
from Parcel p
where DateOfArrival = cast(DateOfArrival as Date);
```

By casting the value to a date, the `datetime` portion is lost.  If the original value equals this, then there is no time component.

Comment: Thanks, that is simple enough

Answer (score 2):

A way to do this would be to convert it in your select statement, for example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DateOfArrival) Date, *other columns*
FROM Parcel P
```

Another solution, would be converting it to VARCHAR, formatting it in a yyyyMMdd format, like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DateOfArrival, 112) Date, *other columns*
FROM Parcel P
```

And if you want to sort it or group it, you have to use the conversion.
I hope it was helpful!

Comment: Please, ***don't convert*** dates to `varchar` !! Use the appropriate datatypes - `DATE` if you don't care about time, or `DATETIME & DATETIME2(n)` if you need time, too

Comment: Really? Does it decrease efficiency?

Comment: Yes, because if you want to do anything with it, now you have to convert it back to a `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` .....

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.*
from Parcel p
where cast(DateOfArrival as time) = '00:00'
```